# How to resolve error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

```
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",db="mja_database")
    myCursor = conn.cursor()
    myCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mja_attendance WHERE emp_num='%s'"%emp_numtb.get())
    res=myCursor.fetchone()
    if res[1] == None and res[3] == None:
        messagebox.showinfo("Notification", "No data in yet.")
```

the error is this

> 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Does it give you a line number as to where NoneType is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

If I had to take a guess to save my life, I would guess that res is None when you check it with your:

```
if res[1]...
```

Maybe put in?

```
res=myCursor.fetchone()
if not res:
    messagebox.showinfo("Notification", "Res is None")
elif res[1] == None and res[3] == None:
    messagebox.showinfo("Notification", "No data in yet.")
```

If you need more help you should put more details in the question.

Answer (score -2):

```
def resul(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10,g11,g12,g13,g14):


    run=enter(g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10,g11,g12,g13,g14)
    d=run.Tmoy



    messagebox.showinfo(title="Resultat", message='NUT = {}\n E={} \nT1s ={} C°'.format( d[0], d[1], d[2]))





messagebox.showinfo(title="Resultat", message='NUT = {}\n E={} \nT1s ={} C°'.format( d[0], d[1], d[2]))
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```